# How to specify Python requirements by allowing prereleases?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I am having some kind of confusion regarding the right way of declaring requirements of Python packages.

New builds that are not officially released yes do have pre-release names like `0.2.3.dev20160513165655`.

pip is really smart to install pre-releases when we add `--pre` option and when we are building the develop branch we do use it. Master branch does not use it.

I discovered that if I put `foobar>=0.2.3` in a requirements file the development version will not be picked even if I specified the --pre parameter.

The [pip documentation](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) is not helping here too much because is missing to point anything about pre-releases.

I used the approach of putting `foobar>0.2.2` which in conjunction with `--pre` would install the pre-release.

Still even this if a bit flawed because if we release a hotfix like `0.2.2.1` it may have picked it.

So, what's the best approach to deal with this?

Side note: It would be highly desired not to have to patch the requirement file when we do make a release (a pull request from develop to master). Please remember that develop branch is always using `--pre` and the master doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else coming across this question, the answer is [in the same documentation](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pre-release-versions):

> If a Requirement specifier includes a pre-release or development version (e.g. `>=0.0.dev0`) then pip will allow pre-release and development versions for that requirement. This does not include the != flag.

Hence, specifying `>=0.2.3.dev0` or similar should pick the "newest" prerelease.

Note that if you already have `0.2.3` released, it will always sort "newer" than prereleases such as `0.2.3.dev20160513165655`. [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#developmental-releases) says the following:

> The developmental release segment consists of the string `.dev`, followed by a non-negative integer value. Developmental releases are ordered by their numerical component, immediately before the corresponding release (and before any pre-releases with the same release segment), and following any previous release (including any post-releases).

It also says:

> ... publishing developmental releases of pre-releases to general purpose public index servers is strongly discouraged, as it makes the version identifier difficult to parse for human readers. If such a release needs to be published, it is substantially clearer to instead create a new pre-release by incrementing the numeric component.
>
> Developmental releases of post-releases are also strongly discouraged ...

So ideally you would not use a datestamp, but something like `dev1`, `dev2`, `dev3`. I think the PEP is actually saying you should use `0.2.3.dev1`, `0.2.4.dev1`, `0.2.5.dev1`, but either is equally readable. It really depends on how many builds you are producing.

In your case, if `0.2.3` is already released, all the subsequent development releases need to be `0.2.4.dev20160513165655` so that `pip` will see it as newer.