# pip install --pre without installing pre-releases for dependencies

Tags: python, pip, release

Say I have a package `A` on pypi with a pre-release version `1.0.0rc1`.

Package `A` has package `B` as a dependency with version `B >= 1.0.0`, but `B` also has a pre-release version `1.0.0rc1` that is incompatible with `A`.

I want to be able to pip install the pre-release version of `A` while installing the regular (not-pre) release version of `B`.

`pip install --pre A` seems to install `A 1.0.0rc1` and `B 1.0.0rc1`.

Are there any recommendations for dealing with this scenario? A few that I've considered

1. pin the version of `B==1.0.0`, but this is a bit limiting and requires me to periodically update as new releases of `B` come out.
2. tell users to `pip install A==1.0.0rc1`, which is slightly less convenient.

What is the standard approach here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is ages after the original post, but i think [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54330251).

Basically to chieve what you want you should use the following

`pip install "A>=1.0.0rc0"`

by specifying the prerelease tag in your version requirement then pip will allow pre-release and development versions matching for that requirement